getting "entry point not found Qt6Gui.dll" error while running the wing ide
I installed the wing on a remote machine which has windows 8.1 system running on it. I am trying to run the app after installation but it is giving me the following error:
The procudure entry point systemParametersinfoForDpi could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\Program files\Wing personal 10\bi_os_\win32\runtime-qt6.5\Qt6Gui.dll
I uninstalled it few times and installed once again. but error doesnt go away. I copied the dll from zip file and pasted it in the location but the problem persists. Does any one know what to do
